# Gulp / Wiredep builds with full path prepended to base64 images embedded in css

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bower, wiredep

Using wiredep + ng-poly, I have a main file from angular toasty.

```
"main": [
    "dist/angular-toasty.js",
    "dist/angular-toasty.css"
],
```

In the angular-toasty.css, there are Base64 PNGs:

```
url("data:font/ttf;base64,AAEAAAASAQAABAAgR0RF....")
```

How do I tell wiredep to ignore these urls so it doesn't produce a local path when I deploy?

```
file:///C:/.../bower_components/angular-toasty/dis…AAAAEACAABACwAAQAIAAEABACg
```

Comment: did you try to add the files to ignore, or array with a ! prefix? Is it a bower package you need for production? if not, you may install it as --save-dev and wiredep wont pick it up, since is not production.

Comment: Check the [wiredep options](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#configuration)
I think that, you may add your filepath/array to the exclude options.
Alternatively, You can override your bower.json file to ignore those files.

Comment: It is for a production package. When developing locally, and not minifying the css, there are no issues.

Comment: add ignorePath: 'file:///C:/.../bower_components/angular-toasty/' on your wiredep options. if not, add .pipe(gulp.dest('destinationPath')) to the task to specify where to deploy

Comment: This may be related to this, after noticing the project uses this project.  https://github.com/kjbekkelund/gulp-css-rebase-urls/issues/6

Comment: I see.. sorry couldn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the issue is the way that ng-poly builds resources. I'm on a little bit dated so, I'm going to post my fix here for those that may stumble on this later.

In the build.js file, under 'bowerCopy', there is a normalization technique that doesn't deal with data: urls properly.  This is the code I used to take care of this issue.

```
      .pipe($.if(isProd, $.modifyCssUrls({
    modify: function (url, filePath) {
      if (url.indexOf('http') !== 0 && url.indexOf('data:') !== 0) {
        filePath = path.dirname(filePath) + path.sep;
        filePath = filePath.substring(filePath.indexOf(bowerDir) + bowerDir.length,
          filePath.length);
      } else if (url.indexOf('data:') === 0) {
        // If it's 0, just return it....
        return url;
      }
      url = path.normalize(filePath + url);
      url = url.replace(/[/\\]/g, '/');
      return url;
    }
  })))
```

I added the "else if" statement.